# How to configure nexus-cli with environment variables

Tags: linux, nexus

I am using nexus-cli to automate the process of nexus repository cleanup with Shell script, I have configured the nexus-cli with credentials manually.

```
$ ./nexus-cli configure
Enter Nexus Host: https://MY_HOST.com
Enter Nexus Repository Name: docker
Enter Nexus Username: USER_NAME
Enter Nexus Password: PASS
```

i'm able to list & delete the Docker images from repository, I want to automate the process of `nexus-cli configure`(like passing the credentials as a parameter) with shell script.

the nexus-cli Credentials file:
    ~/.credentials

```
# Nexus Credentials
nexus_host = "https://MY_HOST.com"
nexus_username = "USER_NAME"
nexus_password = "PASS"
nexus_repository = "docker"
```

How can I achieve this, can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Write the `~/.credentials` file yourself. E.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=myuser
PASS=mypass
REPO=myrepo
HOST=myhost

# protect file since it contains secrets
touch ~/.credentials && chmod 600 ~/.credentials

# update file using environment variables
cat << _EOF > ~/.credentials
# Nexus Credentials
nexus_host = "${HOST}"
nexus_username = "${USER}"
nexus_password = "${PASS}"
nexus_repository = "${REPO}"
_EOF

cat ~/.credentials
# Nexus Credentials
nexus_host = "myhost"
nexus_username = "myuser"
nexus_password = "mypass"
nexus_repository = "myrepo"
```